# Tengo un error de "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones, while, opencv

Muy buen dia amigos una ayuda tengo un error con mi codigo es para detectar un indicador Aruco y poder medir objetos en tiempo real pero me da ese error este es el codigo completo no se que hacer la verdad estoy muy novato en esto de python.
no se q pueda ser supongo que es dentro del `while` el `if` o el `for` pero no tengo idea y en cuanto a la lectura de la camara solo tengo como conectar la camara del cel por medio de droidcam y no por USB ya que esta fallando mi celular, si me pueden ayudar les agradezco mucho

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv2 import *

class DetectorFondoHomogeneo():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def deteccion_objetos(self, frame):
        # convertir imagen a escala de grises
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # crea una mascara con umbral adaptativo
        mask = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 19, 5)

        # encontramos contornos
        contornos, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        # creamos una lista donde almacenaremos los objetos
        objetos_contornos = []

        # si encontramos contornos entramos al for
        for cnt in contornos:
            # medimos el area de los contornos
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            # si el area es mayor a 2000 agregamos el objeto a la lista
            if area > 2000:
                objetos_contornos.append(cnt)

        return objetos_contornos


# cargamos el detector del marcador aruco

parametros = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
diccionario = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_100)

# cargamos el detector de objetos
detector = DetectorFondoHomogeneo()

# realizamos la videocaptura de nuestra camara
url = 'http://192.168.100.233:4747'
cap = VideoCapture(url+'/video',cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

# accedemos al while principal
while True:
    # realizamos la lectura de la camara
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
    #mostramos los fotogramas

    # Aruco Marker
    # detectamos el marcador aruco
    esquinas, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(frame, diccionario, parameters=parametros)
    esquinas_ent = np.int0(esquinas)
    cv2.polylines(frame, esquinas_ent, True, (0,0,255),5)
    # Perimetro del Aruco
    perimetro_aruco = cv2.arcLength(esquinas_ent[0], True)
    #print(perimetro_aruco)

    # Proporcion en cm
    proporcion_cm = perimetro_aruco / 16
    #print(proporcion_cm)

    # Deteccion objetos
    # Detectamos los objetos
    contornos = detector.deteccion_objetos(frame)

    # Dibujamos la detecciondel objeto
    for cont in contornos:
        # Dibujamos el contorno del objeto
        cv2.polylines(frame, [cont], True, (0,255,0),2)

        # Rectangulo del objeto
        # a partir del poligono anterior vamos a obtener un rectangulo
        rectangulo = cv2.minAreaRect(cont)
        (x, y), (an, al), angulo = rectangulo

        # pasamos el ancho y el alto de pixeles a centimetros
        ancho = an / proporcion_cm
        alto = al / proporcion_cm

        # dibujamos un circulo en la mitad del rectangulo
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)),5,(255,255,0), -1)

        # Vamos a dibujar el rectangulo que ya obtuvimos
        rect = cv2.boxPoints(rectangulo)  # obtenemos el rectangulo
        rect = np.int0(rect)  # Aseguramos que toda la informacion este en enteros

        # Dibujamos el rectangulo
        cv2.polylines(frame, [rect], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # mostramos la info en pixeles
        cv2.putText(frame, "Ancho: {} cm".format(round(ancho, 1)), (int(x), int(y-15)), cv2.LINE_AA, 0.8, (150,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(frame, "Largo: {} cm".format(round(alto, 1)), (int(x), int(y+15)), cv2.LINE_AA, 0.8, (75,0,75),2)
    cv2.imshow('Medicion de Objetos', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
            break
```

Comment: En qué linea te dice que está dando el error?

Comment: aca en esta parte  esquinas, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(frame, diccionario, parameters=parametros) aunq en lugar de ids no paso ese parametro osea quedaria  esquinas, _, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(frame, diccionario, parameters=parametros)

Comment: Justo antes de la línea que mencionas hay un `if ret == True:` por tanto tras los dos puntos la línea siguiente debe ir indentada más adentro (y seguramente un montón de líneas más, todas las que quieras que se ejecuten solamente si el `if` se cumple). Aparte de esto parece que tienes otra indentación incorrecta al final, pues tras el `imshow()` las dos líneas siguientes están más metidas. Revisa si lo que quieres es hacer el `imshow()` como parte del `for` o no, así como el `if cv2.waitKey()`

Comment: al realizar el imshow() con el if me da este error cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor' para la linea mensionada, y si lo dejo dentro del for parece que se ejecuta pero no me sale lo que debería de mostrar el imshow(), osea se queda ejecutado pero no muestra nada

Comment: ahora presento un error en esta parte, perimetro_aruco = cv2.arcLength(esquinas_ent[0], True)
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0, parece q intenta utilizar la camara pero me da ese error.

Comment: Hola Anthony, si tienes un nuevo problema te pediría que abrieras una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema así es más facil para todo el mundo encontrarlo en el futuro y no mezclamos soluciones y comentarios en una misma pregunta